# Mysql innodb crash due to buffer pool size

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb

There are lots of solutions/answer but in my case nothing is working, Mysql is keep crashing, i have try to tune but issue still persist.

Mysql is running on AWS instance with following specs

Single core 
4 GB RAM, 1.5 GB swap

After tinning, following are my.cnf details

[mysqld]

```
#Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
datadir=/mnt/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0
lower_case_table_names=2
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
#innodb_force_recovery = 4

max_connections=250
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
skip-external-locking
thread_cache_size = 4
key_buffer_size = 512M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M
innodb_log_file_size = 750M
join_buffer_size = 128K
tmp_table_size = 750MB
max_heap_table_size = 290MB
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 128K
table_open_cache = 512
wait_timeout = 86400
table_cache = 2500
long_query_time=4
max_allowed_packet = 32M
innodb_use_sys_malloc =  0

#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:20M:autoextend

#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M

#innodb_log_file_size = 64M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

following are logs thats shows that "cannot allocate memory to buffer pool size" even i have assigned 1.5 gb.

```
140808 09:50:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140808 09:50:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mnt/data/mysql
140808  9:50:07 [Warning] lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system '/mnt/data/mysql/' is case sensitive.  Now setting lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems.
140808  9:50:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.5G
InnoDB: mmap(1609728000 bytes) failed; errno 12
140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
**140808  9:50:07 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool**
140808  9:50:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140808  9:50:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140808  9:50:07 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140808  9:50:07 [ERROR] Aborting

140808  9:50:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Please advice should i increase physical resources and increase it buffer pool size?
Or there is any application malfunctioning that cause to overgrow db buffer size.

Comment: How big is your database?

Comment: @luke db size is 6 GB

Comment: I have upgrade system, till now it is working fine.